# Set distance between labels and chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart and I would like to increase the distance between y axis labels and the chart (light blue lines) - check the image, more distance between 10k and the blue lines

[image]

In y axis I tried to combine the settings of yAxis offset, yAxis labels padding and yAxis title margin, but no success

How do I achieve this?

These are the settings of the chart

```
       options: {              
          chart: { 
            updateArgs: [false, false, true],
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginLeft: 40,
            marginRight: 2,
            type:'line',
            zoomType: 'x',
            animation: false,
            height:250,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }, 
            panning:true 
          },
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          time:{
            useUTC:true
          },  
          credits:{
            enabled:false
          },
          tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: this.tooltipFormatter
          },
          title:{
            text:null
          },
          lang: {
            noData: 'loading...'
          },
          rangeSelector: {
            inputEnabled: false
          },
          xAxis:{
            type:'datetime',
            max:this.maxdate,
            min:this.mindate,
            title:
            {
              align:'high'
            }, 
            labels: {
              padding: 50,
              format: '{value:%H:%M}',
              style: {
                fontSize: '10px'
              }
            },
            crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                width: 1,
                color: '#000'
            },
            events : {
                afterSetExtremes : this.afterSetExtremes
            }
          },   
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: this.streamChart.title + '  [' + this.streamChart.unit+']',
              margin:20,
              fontSize:"15px"
            },
            labels: {
              step: 2,
              staggerLines: 2,
              enabled:true,
              align: 'left',
              padding:0
            },
            alignTicks:'left', 
            textAlign:'left',
            align:'middle', 
            opposite:false, 
            offset:0
          },    
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              animation: false,
              boostThreshold: 1,
              pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
            }
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },
          responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: '100%',
                    minHeight: 300
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    subtitle: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                      title: {
                        enabled: false
                      }
                    }
                }
            }]
          }   
          ,series: [{ 
            name:this.streamChart.title,
            id:this.streamChart.id,
            data:[]
          }],

      },
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase `chart.marginLeft` and enable `reserveSpace` or align labels by `x` property:

```
labels: {
  ...,
  reserveSpace: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/71gxj4sd/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.reserveSpace

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.x